# Javascript Object, can't find 'quantity'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on creating a shopping list app for a grocery stores website. I'm new to javascript, and I don't understand javascript objects very well yet.

I started creating the app and this is what I had:
http://casb1.cloudapp.net/1024/92da5d49e7b5cbfd68388a7742e5dd54/shopping%20list/jqtest.html

Then someone better with Javascript than me suggested storing the data in an object instead of using the html output. So I began re-structuring the app and now I have this:

http://casb1.cloudapp.net/1024/92da5d49e7b5cbfd68388a7742e5dd54/shopping%20list/jqtest2.html

When you try to add an item now, it doesn't work. It spurts out this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined
```

This error is happening at this location:
line 125:

```
p.listhtml += '<li>' + p.items[i]['quantity'] +' - '+ p.items[i]['item'] +' <input type="button" href="#" class="killwithfire" value="trash"></li>';
```

I've left a lot of comments in the code to hopefully make it easier to read.

can anyone tell me what is wrong with it? I didn't make a typo... and a value should be there because of my add to list function...

Thank you ahead of time to anyone who offers help.

Comment: hum hum... don't hit your head on a wall, you swear ? your for loop goes one step too far : for( var i = 0; i <= p.items.length; i++ ) should read : for( var i = 0; i < p.items.length; i++ ). Now you can just thank me and delete your question, no-one will know ;-)

Comment: lol thank you. Oy I love javascript but find it more picky than other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating one too many times. Replace `<=` by `<` in your `for` loop.
You are iterating 3 times. The third time `i` equals 2. But index 2 is out of range for your array.

```
for( var i = 0; i < p.items.length; i++ ){
}
```

Comment: Well you appear to be right, changing this stopped the error displaying in console. now I have a new issue... it's not printing the list at all... ugh I'm starting to regret trying to build this thing.